# Using dynamic library with native code(build with framework v4.0) in dotnet core

Tags: .net, .net-core, dllexport, coreclr

I had build a `dll` build using dotnet `framework v4.0`. The code in the library is like below

```
`extern "C"  
 {
      __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b) 
      {
          printf("Unmanaged add()");
          return a+b;
      }
      __declspec(dllexport) int subtract(int a,int b) 
      {
          printf("Unmanaged subtract()");
          return a-b;
      }
}`
```

Now i need to refer this dll in **.Net Core Application**. For that i have made the `Nuget` package containing this dll and finally installed this `nuget` package.

The `dll` is referenced is quite visible in `project.json` file under its dependency section.

Now the **.Net Core Application** is like this

```
{

        [DllImport("vs2010_nativelib.dll", CallingConvention =                                                    CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int subtract(int a, int b);`

        [DllImport("vs2010_nativelib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int add(int a, int b);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Managed Dot Net Core 1.0 Application ");
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Unamanged add : {0}", add(10, 20));
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Unamanged subtract : {0}", subtract(30, 20));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

While running this application, the  moment it calls `add(10, 20)` function of unmanaged dll it throws `BadImageFormatException` with this message `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

So where is the problem ? Does .Net Core cannot use these types of libraries or there something else i am missing ?

Comment: Are both of them compiled for the same target platform? One could be 64 bit and the other 32 bit and you'd get exactly this error

Comment: Yes. this was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the native code dll and the .Net core application dll are of same platform as your Machine configuration(ex : 64 bit).

Comment: Yes ...this was the problem